# Fake Brownian Motion

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, martingales

Does there exist a martingale which has Marginal distributions same as Brownian Motion marginals but the process itself not being Brownian motion? Any references are highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by marginals?  Marginals at a single time?  At finitely many times?

Comment: Marginal distribution at any time t should be Gaussian with zero mean and variance t.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks relevant.

Kais Hamza and Fima C. Klebaner, *“A Family of Non-Gaussian Martingales with Gaussian Marginals,”* Journal of Applied Mathematics and Stochastic Analysis, vol. 2007, Article ID 92723, 19 pages, 2007. doi:10.1155/2007/92723

http://www.hindawi.com/journals/ijsa/2007/092723/abs/

Comment: Hi this could be usefull aswell : http://peer.ccsd.cnrs.fr/docs/00/62/21/42/PDF/PEER_stage2_10.1016%252Fj.spl.2007.11.026.pdf